# Drupal - Cron is blocked on executing

Tags: drupal, cron, drupal-7

I have a little cron function in one of my modules, I try to launch it this morning and it works well, I launch a second time (without change anything) and since that the cron function is blocked on executing (usually it takes like 1-2 seconds) since 15minutes, I try to flush the cache, remove an replace the cron function but anything change.

Anyone have an idea of what is going on ?

Comment: Are you using Elysia cron api ?

Comment: Is the watchdog log showing any error messages? For example `Tried to run cron while it is still running`?